# Why does testing for instanceOf in my unit tests fail?

Tags: javascript, karma-jasmine

**Background**

I have a class which has one getter function that returns an array of *child* objects that are initialized with the constructor. In my unit tests, I want to verify that the child objects created are instances of the class, but for some reason, `instanceOf` is returning `false` rather than `true`.

**The Code**

My class:

```
function Class(data) {
  this.data = data
}

Class.prototype = {
  get children() {
    return _.each(this.data.children, function(child) {
      return new Class(child);
    });
  }
}
```

My test:

```
it('should instantiate each child', function() {
  var classInstance = new Class({
    children: [
      /* ... */
    ]
  });

  classInstance.children.forEach(function (child) {
    expect(child).to.be.an.instanceOf(Class);  //THIS FAILS
  });
});
```

Interestingly, `expect(classInstance).to.be.an.instanceOf(Class);` passes. What is the reason for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your test is failing because it should fail. I think your getter function should look like:

```
return _.map(this.data.children, function(child) {
  return new Class(child);
});
```

That is, `_.map()` instead of `_.each()`, since you want to build an array to return. The `return` statements, when you use `_.each()`, really don't do anything, and `_.each()` just returns the original array.

Comment: Thank you! I hadn't realized that `_.each` only returned the original array.

Comment: @A.Duff no problem! I guess that's what tests are for :)